# How to grab thumbnail every X seconds from *live* Windows Media Stream

Tags: c#, windows-media-player, windows-media-server

I want to provide a choice between streaming 'channels', if you will, in a web application. These are **Windows Media streams** of **live events** that are being broadcast from a **Windows Media Services 9** distribution network.

I want to provide a relatively recent thumbnail image of the stream (as a user, you would expect to see this), but although I've seen this done in Flash on CNN and countless other sites, I've never seen this done with Windows Media.

I already have a C# / DirectX library that can extract a thumbnail from a WMV file, but obviously the stream doesn't come from a file if it's a live source.

My assumptions so far are:

1. Will need to run some kind of service application/daemon that will receive a stream into a Windows Media Player object and somehow take thumbnails if WMPlayer supports it...

   **-or-**
2. Configure the streams to archive to file, and use the existing class library to take a peek at the last frame available in the archive file being written to get the thumbnail.

I would much rather do #1 because it seems like the clean solution, but don't know if/how WMPlayer supports grabbing a frame.

Are there better ways of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if using media player is a good idea in such case. I would look into this:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/windowsmedianet/